# ERROR: data type text[] has no default operator class for access method "gist"

Tags: postgresql, index, array, gist-index

Whenever I try to try to create a GIST index on `text[]`, I get the above error.

```
CREATE TABLE bar(f)
AS VALUES
  (ARRAY['foo','bar','baz']);

CREATE INDEX ON bar USING gist(f);

ERROR:  data type text[] has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

I'm trying to [create an *Exclusion Constraint*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185177/2639) on bar, so I need a GIST index.

Answer (score 2):

## `smlar` Extension

I was able to create a gist index on a text[] column using the [`smlar` extension](http://sigaev.ru/git/gitweb.cgi?p=smlar.git) (written by Teodor Sigaev of text search fame)

```
# git clone git://sigaev.ru/smlar.git
# cd smlar/
# PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1
# PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1 install
# psql

postgres=# create extension smlar;
postgres=# create index on bar using gist(f _text_sml_ops);
```

Comment: Wonder why that's not in core then =(

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create the index converting the column to `ts_vector`, this way you will not need to install `smlar`.

```sql
create index on bar using gist(array_to_tsvector(f));
```

When using the index, make sure you're using operations supported by tsvector, such as:

```sql
select * from bar where to_tsquery('search_value') @@ array_to_tsvector(f);
```